# For and while loop not working in a globally defined function

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int help(int i,int money,int denomination[]){
    int sum=0;
    int j=0;
    while(i>0){
        if(i&1) sum+=denomination[j];
        i=i>>1;
        j+=1;
    }
    return sum==money?1:0;
}

int ans(int numOfNotes,int money,int denomination[]){
    for(int i=0;i<(1<<numOfNotes);i++){
        if(help(i,money,denomination)){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}  

int main() {
    int testCases,numOfNotes,money;
    cin>>testCases;
    while(testCases>0){
        cin>>numOfNotes>>money;
        int denomination[numOfNotes];
        int i=0;
        while(numOfNotes){
            cin>>denomination[i];
            i++;
            numOfNotes--;
        }
        testCases--;
        ans(numOfNotes,money,denomination)==1?cout<<"Yes"<<endl:cout<<"No"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If there exists a subset of array `denomination` such that it amounts to `money`, program should show "Yes", else "No".

But for the following simple input

```
1
3 3
1
1
1
```

output is coming out to be

> No

whereas it should be

> Yes

According to me, the `for` and `while` loops are not working in the `ans` and `help` functions. Is there any other bug in the program?

Comment: what exactly is the output? warnings or errors on compile?

Comment: Having to start your answer with explaining what each variable means should be a hint that perhaps the variables should be named better, to alleviate such need.

Comment: @Angew,variable names improved

Comment: @Mixone,input and output mentioned

Comment: I see where the error is more or less

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying `numOfNotes` in the inner while loop in `main`, which means its value is 0 when later passed to `ans`. The loops in the functions are working, you're just giving them other limits than you expected.

You can easily solve issues like this yourself by stepping through your program in a debugger and inspecting variable values and control flow along the way. This is a vital programming skill. See also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

---

Unrelated to the problem at hand, but please also see these SO questions about what's wrong with [including `bits/stdc++.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/1782465) and [declaring `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1782465).

Comment: yeah, like he says, you named a variable i in the function declaration but that does not mean that because you have a variable named i elsewhere it will be used